# updating angular2 seed from repo to my custom project that uses angular seed

Tags: git, angular

I am using angular2 seed from here.

https://github.com/mgechev/angular2-seed

i have cloned the project and added my own controllers. The project is a seperate repository.It works fine.

The seed repository is actively updated. Is it possible to get the updates when from the seed repo to my angular2 repo.

now what i am doing is replacing all other folders other than the src folder where i have my code, is there a better way to do this?

@Günter Zöchbauer suggested i do a git merge from upstream repo but in my case i have changed the remote origin, it no more the angular seed repo.

Comment: You could use Gits merge feature to merge from the upstream repo to your custom repo.

Comment: i have changed my remote origin,
now is it possible to do a merge. If possible could you please advice about how to do it?

Comment: This is not related to Angular, only to Git. I'm not a Git expert myself. I'm sure there are tons of tutorials available for this common use case.

Comment: Something like `git remote add upstream https://github.com/mgechev/angular2-seed.git` and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/520650/make-an-existing-git-branch-track-a-remote-branch